# Save belongsTo change in model not part of Payload

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm trying to save a change to a parent model on a child model in Ember to my server, but for some reason the REST Payload doesn't contain the belongsTo Relationship

My 2 models are defined like this:

**parent.js**

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  parentName: DS.attr('string')
});
```

**child.js**

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  childName: DS.attr('string'),
  parent: DS.belongsTo('parent')
});
```

when I change the belongsTo to a different parent for a childModel by editing and saving an existing record. Somehow my payload doesnt include the parent model.

For example.

I have a child like this:

```
{
    id: 1,
    parent: 1,
    childName: "Child 1"
}
```

and in code I do this:

```
childModel.set('parent', parentModel); // this is a different parentModel, one with id: 2
```

I would expect the payload to look something like this:

HTTP-PUT: http://server/child/1

```
{
    id: 1,
    parent: 2,
    childName: "Child 1"
}
```

however, in reality, the payload is this:

HTTP-PUT: http://server/child/1

```
{
    id: 1,
    childName: "Child 1"
}
```

What goes wrong here? Why is the parent relationship missing from the payload?

Some extra information:

1. Ember v2.0.1
2. Ember-data v2.0.0
3. Relationships must be async: true (which is the default)
4. I'm using a standard DS.JSONAPISerializer in combination with the DS.RestAdapter

Answer (score 0):

Turns out during the serialization, I only extracted the attributes hash from my JSON Api - JSON, Obviously I need to look for relationships in the relationships hash.

Comment: Can you share your changes? Was this on the server side or ember side?